# How to check if a table row is editable in selenium?

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, xpath

I have a table row that needs to be checked if it is editable or not. So once i click on the particular row, the html for the row shows up this.

```
<tr data-bind="event: { mousedown: $component.setCurrentRow, click: $component.rowClickEvent, dblclick: $component.rowDblClickEvent },
                                        css: {'fp-grid-row-selected': IsSelected} " style="display: table-row;" class="fp-grid-row-selected"> == $0
```

I want to check if the row is editable or not using selenium. This is ofcourse a read only row, but I do not see that attribute anywhere in the code.

How do I check if the row is editable or not.

Comment: If you could also provide the HTML for a similar row that is editable, it owuld be easier to spot the difference.

Comment: is this the code when row is editable or when NOT? you have to check which component is changing, mostly class. based on that you can write your own function.

Comment: none of the rows are editable

Comment: @GaurangShah this is the code all the time. there is no difference otherwise. The only difference is the 'class="fp-grid-row-selected"' appears in the tag  when I click on it. But that wont serve my purpose I guess

Comment: I have the same issue